# Equivalence of representation form of an AR(1)

Tags: autoregressive

I've an AR(1) model: $y_t = a_0 +a_1y_{t-1}+\epsilon_t$.
How can I demonstrate that the following form is equivalent?

$y_t$ = $\dfrac{a_0}{(1-a_1)} + \mu_t$

where $\mu_t = a_1\mu_{t-1} + \epsilon_t$

Comment: Hint: the purpose is to remove $a_0$ from $y_t$ to produce $\mu_t$, whose defining equation does not involve any additive constant.  To that end, subtract some unknown constant $\lambda$ from every $y_t$ (for all indexes $t$, not just one particular one).  Plug that into the defining equation of the model.  Solve for $\lambda$.

Comment: @whuber Can you add more details please? I'm not understand very well what I've to do